# Why is my calculated column sum different than my natural column sum in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my Power BI report I have a column for a Gross Margin Amount that is set to sum in visualizations, and I have a calculated column that calculates the sum of the GMA for each product. However, when I use them in a visualization, they are different. The code for the calculated column is:

```
SumMargin = 
VAR Margin = 'PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin'[productRef]
RETURN
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin'[groupExtGrossMarginAmt] ),
    FILTER (
        'PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin', 
        'PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin'[productRef] = Margin
        )
    )
```

and the code that Power BI uses when you drag the original GMA column into a visualization is:

```
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin'[groupExtGrossMarginAmt] ) )
```

To my understanding, these should be the same, but the calculated column's values are way different. This is the case for nearly every product, and I don't understand why. Could anyone offer some insight or advice? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer likely has to do with [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/). Does the SumMargin calculated column match the original GMA column?

Comment: No, the original GMA column has individual values that the calculated column is supposed to sum up. I actually just finished going through and calculating the sum for a product where the DAX generated code and my code didn't have an equal result and it seems that my code is actually summing it properly, and the DAX code isn't. I'm very confused right now. Essentially, if you make the GMA column a sum in the summarized option up top, and then drag it into a table visual with the product name, it's supposed to show that product sum but it's wrong and my calculated column is correct.

Comment: I will look through that link and see if that helps me get a different understanding of what's going on, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to get sum of amount by product you can create below measure:

```
SumMargin = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin'[groupExtGrossMarginAmt] ),
    FILTERS ('PRO vw_FactProfitability_Margin'[productRef]))
```

Creating a visual with  SumMargin along with ProductRef will give you amount group by productRef

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this out and see if it helps me

Comment: It seems like this as a measure didn't help, but is it possible to get this as a calculated column?

Comment: It will help if you can share the sample screenshot of visual you are trying to make and error you are getting while using this measure